# How to update DrawerLabel text (via navigationOptions) on DrawerOpen/Close event

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have define drawerLabel in navigationOptions as follows :

```
export default class Something extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon: () => (
      <Image source={drawerImage} style={styles.imageStyle} />
    ),

   drawerLabel: ()=>{

        if(~some condition~){
                return 'New Label'
            }else if(~some other condition~){  
                return 'Another Label'
            }else{
                return 'label'
            }            
    },
};
```

This updates the label perfectly when any drawerItem is pressed in the drawer.

(apparently opening ANY drawer item updates the navigationOptions of all routes)

**But I want this drawerLabel to be updated  on drawer.Open() call as well.**
*or when left-header is pressed on any screen (triggers drawer.Open() )*

So, how can I achieve this behaviour on DrawerOpen/Close ? 
I am able to achieve this on pressing any drawerItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired output as follows (im afraid it might cause performance issues in the long run) :

I created a custom component and forced it to re-render every second using :

```
componentDidMount() {
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now() }), 1000);   }
```

And used that component in the navigationOption's drawerLabel :

```
drawerLabel: ()=> {        
    return <CustomComponent  />
    }
```

Now it does not need a click event on either any drawerItem or in drawerToggle call. (label gets updated even if the drawer is left open and no click is fired at all)

Following is the CustomComponent's render code :

```
 if(~some condition~){
            return <Text> New Label </Text>
        }else if(~some other condition~){  
            return <Text> Another Label </Text>
        }else{
            return <Text>label</Text>
        }
```

Now the if/else condition gets checked every second and a Text component is rendered as a label accordingly.

Even though I managed to achieve what I required, I would like to know if this affects the performance of the application? 
(if so should I optimize this somehow? ... async maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Pass navigation prop to your navigationOptions.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        drawerLabel: ()=>{ // maybe you also need to pass navigation to this function through the parentheses (navigation)

            if(~some condition~){
                return navigation.state.params.labels.first
            }else if(~some other condition~){  
                return navigation.state.params.labels.second
            }else{
                return navigation.state.params.labels.third
            }            
        },
    });
```

Obviously, you need to create the labels:

```
navigation.setParams({ labels: { first: 'labelOne', second: 'labelTwo', third: 'labelThree' }})
```

before you can access them.

If you don't understand how to add the labels to the params - don't hesitate asking.

You can also use [screenProps](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options), if you have static labels. In this case you will need to define these props in your **root-navigator**. After that you will be able to access them in `navigationOptions` if you pass them alongside with navigation:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
```

Comment: sure please explain how to add labels to params. 
I'll try and let you know...

Also, are you saying that by passing this prop to navOptions, these options will be updated on drawerOpen call automagically?
(it is updating the label automatically on any drawerItem clicks at the moment, without the navigation prop )

Comment: @AfnanAhmer by "updating labels automatically at the moment" you mean setting "New Label", "Another label" etc? My solution simply returns the values that you set to the appropriate props of navigation.state.params. And if you set the values you need to them, then yes, it should update automatically, just don't forget to return them from inside of if-statement.

Comment: already able to set the labels. 
drawerLabel : () => { THIS METHOD is triggered each time a drawer item from Drawer is clicked. 

I need to trigger this method on drawer.Open aswell so labels are updated each time Drawer is opened rather than on-click of drawer items as it happens currently  }

Comment: how do you open your Drawer? onClick, onSwipe? Provide some details, please.

Comment: navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")... or DrawerToggle... 
I solved the issue . Check my answer to this question